# NGINX Proxy Pass not working properly

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I tried setting up NGINX as a reverse proxy for routing to different servers, but I encountered some issues.

So I basically want to access different LXD containers on my server with the hostname "webserver" under different URL paths. When I access http://webserver/service1/some/path I want it to pass the request to the container, so that the container receives the request http://service1/some/path.

This is my config file (I substituted the name of the container and port with "service1"):

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name webserver;

  location /service1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    #rewrite /service1/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://service1;
    sub_filter "http://service1/" "http://webserver/service1/";
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types *;

    proxy_redirect http://service1/ http://$host/$uri/;
  }
}
```

I tried to follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290141/nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection) answer at first and it was half successful. I was able to access the service instance running in the container, but assets were missing and I got a 404. I tried various combinations of the configuration options but I couldn't get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**ETA:** The NGINX logs when trying to access the site by "http://webserver/grafana" (grafana is the service I'm hosting as a test and which I want to access):

```
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:49 +0000] "GET /grafana/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"

192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/img/grafana_icon.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://webserver/grafana/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/img/icn-dashboard-tiny.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://webserver/grafana/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/img/graph404.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://webserver/grafana/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "http://webserver/public/build/grafana.dark.75ccb77dbb4b5e3c9285.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "http://webserver/public/build/grafana.dark.75ccb77dbb4b5e3c9285.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
192.168.188.52 - - [04/Sep/2019:15:48:50 +0000] "GET /public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://webserver/public/build/grafana.dark.75ccb77dbb4b5e3c9285.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
```

The request URLs are wrong and not what I want to achieve but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i think your block seems wrongly in my mind, a normal proxypass should work

```
server {
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl http2;
    <server_name domain.local;>


            location /app1 {

                    proxy_set_header        X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                    proxy_cache_valid       200 1w;
                    proxy_pass              <http://10.10.200.4; >                                                      
                    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                    proxy_buffers           16 8m;
                    proxy_buffer_size       2m;
                    gzip on;
                    gzip_vary          on;
                    gzip_comp_level    9;
                    gzip_proxied       any;}}
```

your app should be reachable by domain.local/app1

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. I have the same problem I described above. Also I don't really see the difference between our configs, because the configs relevant for proxies are the same in them, if I'm not mistaken. I will add the NGINX access logs to my post as additional information.